Visualizing bonding and antibonding orbitals
When two Helium atoms come together, they produce a helium dimer molecule with 2 MO - A filled sigma star antibonding orbital and A filled Sigma bonding orbital. I have seen how bonding orbital is represented from constructive inteference - example in diatomic hydrogen where two hydrogen atoms with their atomic 1s orbitals make a larger MO orbital but what about with helium dimer - how would you visualize the antibonding orbitals and bonding orbitals all in the same molecule
